# Possessive determiner for "authorities"

Tags: grammatical-number, determiners

Which possessive determiner should I use for *the authorities*? *Its* seems wrong, but *their* doesn't seem quite right, either. Example:

> After examining all the evidence, I've found that the authorities are
>   right and _____ critics are wrong.

If either *its* or *their* sounds perfectly fine to you, please say so and I'll use it. (In the example above, *the* is also an option, but it would work less well in my actual construction.)

If both of them sound off to you, as they do to me, please say so as well and I'll probably use the noun *government* instead (although I really prefer *authorities* in my context).

Comment: "their" sounds fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Authorities* is a plural noun, so you should use *their*:

> The authorities are right and their critics are wrong.

Using *authorities* is fine, but if you choose to use *government*, it can be a singular noun or plural noun, so you can use *its* or *their*:

> The government is right and its critics are wrong.
>
> The government are right and their critics are wrong.

Comment: A singular government does make sense, but that also requires the verb to change: "the government *is* right and *its* critics are wrong."  Subject/verb agreement is just as important as pronoun/antecedent agreement.